# Why express returns index.html when app.css is requested?

Tags: angularjs, express, gulp

I serve my Angular app using an express server.

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
server.use(express.static('./app'));
server.all('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: './app' });
});
server.listen(8000);
```

[Full `gulpfile.js` is here](https://github.com/moroshko/github-explorer/blob/master/gulpfile.js).

When I navigate to `http://localhost:8000`, my Angular app redirects to `http://localhost:8000/home`, and `app.css` is served properly (I get CSS in the response).

However, if I refresh the page (`http://localhost:8000/home`), the response for `app.css` is `index.html`.

Why is this happening, and how would you fix that?

<kbd>[DEMO HERE](https://github.com/moroshko/github-explorer)</kbd>

Comment: Are you actually watching the network traffic and seeing that the CSS is getting pulled properly on the first page, and isn't coming from the cache? The code here looks like it says "For any request of any method for any file, sendFile index.html. Shouldn't you be passing the request filename rather than the constant string?

Comment: What is the code of your index.html file, especially the part where the css file is included? You should use an absolute path, not a relative one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an absolute path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app.css">
```

Otherwise the request to express for app.css from /home will be home/app.css not /app.css.